# Cannot Create Backup Device - SQL Server 2008 R2, Error 1326 (permissions look ok)

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

Trying to create a backup device for a new db. I'm using management studio and just using the "New Backup Device..." wizard and giving UNC path to the backup directory.

There is a pre-existing db on another server, it has backups working to the same Samba share.

I'm setting up backups for a new db on a new node, same vlan/subnet using the same share, same domain account for the SQL service user.

I can access and read/write just browsing the UNC with Windows Explorer
The share is presented as Samba from Gluster storage on RHEL.

**Node1: Working node:**

Service user: `sqluser@domain.local`, Path:`\\shr01\main-storage\files\dbbackup\db1\full`

**Node2: Not working node:**

Service user: `sqluser@domain.local`  Path: `\\shr01\main-storage\files\dbbackup\db2\full`

Both directories have the same permissions and ownership, I've tried pointing the path from Node2 to the either share but I get the same result with either paths from Node2:

[image: Error1326]

This means that the path can be found, but the permissions aren't working.
The directory is owned by a `sambaadmin@domain.local` user from the file server and can be accessed by BOTH nodes in Windows with full read/write with the service user `sqluser@domain.local`, but it doesn't work via SQL Server backup device creation? Help. Please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out -- Windows credential manager didn't have the credentials stored for the share. After adding the proper creds to the credential manager it worked ok.